# Stretch VMWare Player guest OS to fullscreen

Tags: compatibility, vmware-player, resolution

I’m using VMWare Player to play an old 16-bit Windows game. Unfortunately the game uses only 640x480 and I cannot figure out how to stretch the VM window to full-screen on the host. I set the guest OS to 640x480, but the screen is still small, in the middle of the screen as seen in figure 1.

I even tried setting the compatibility mode to Windows 95 and 640x480, but it has no effect (figure 2) and looks exactly the same as when I set the VM to full-screen (1366x768 on the laptop) and start the game normally.

There are [few references](https://www.google.com/search?q=vmware%20player%20stretch%20guest) to stretching a VM. [One page](http://www.tombraiderforums.com/archive/index.php/t-150150.html) mentions setting a *Stretch Guest* option, but there is no such option, at least not in VMWare Player 4.0.3.

<sup>I know that VirtualBox has a stretching option, but I’m trying to find a solution for VMWare (Player, not Workstation).</sup>

**Figure 1**: Guest OS is pillar-boxed

[image]

**Figure 2**: Using compatibility mode

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Has something changed in this regards with newer VMware Player 6 (and new Vmware Tools)? Also, I can assure that you *can* stretch 16-bit applications to fullscreen using *Stretch guest* + VMware Workstation 7.xx and above + VMware Tools. When back at work I will try it with a Player too.

Comment: This was with VMPlayer 4; maybe they’ve enhanced it since then.

Comment: Have checked it. Unfortunately they haven't added the "Stretch guest" option in VMware Player 6

Comment: I guess we’ll have just have to use the work-around below until they do. ◔̯◔

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a not-ideal-but-effective-nonetheless solution/work-around: **use Unity**.

1. (Use a third-party tool to) set the host OS resolution to 640x480 (ignoring the *Optimal Resolution* warning)
2. Enter Unity in the guest VM
3. Launch the game from the Unity Start menu

**Note:** the order of steps is important.

(Optionally auto-hide the taskbar.)

Yay! The game runs at full-screen on the guest OS instead of a tiny letter- *and* pillar-boxed screen. Now the only problem is that the 16-bit game uses 100% CPU, but there’s not much that can be done about that.

Fullscreen host capture of guest VM running in Unity mode:

[image: Fullscreen host capture of guest VM running in Unity mode]

Comment: Unfortunately, Unity is not supported for Linux guests.